# SSIS: How to parameterise foreach folder loop location from project.params value?

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS Project I want to parameterise to be able to have dev, staging, production environments.

I'm starting slowly, and I'd like to parameterise some hardcoded filepaths.

I have a foreach loop container that iterates over a directory and performs some actions on each of the files it contains.

In Visual Studio I right click and click edit. There are four tabs: General, Collection, Variable Mappings, and Expressions.

Under "Collection", there is a variable Folder. This is hardcoded currently. I'd like it to be at least a package parameter, or preferable, a project parameter followed by a suffix.

Once I've added a project parameter, how can I do this?

For this purpose, let's say I have a variable: SuperFolderLocation.

Would I change the variable Folder's destination to be @[$Project::SuperFolderLocation] + "\subdirectory"? Do I need to use expressions to calculate the variable Folder's destination? If so, what is the variable I need to set? And can you just plop a variable in the Folder destination and it will interpret it?

Comment: Yes you need to use expressions. Once you understand expressions it should all become clear. I suggest you start experimenting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing you need to do is create the project parameter:

[image]

Then in the `foreach loop container` select `collection` and make sure that "Foreach File Enumerator" is selected in the drop down.
Click on `Expressions` and select "Directory" in the `Property` dropdown.
Click on `Expression` ellipsis and this will open the `Expression Builder`
Then select your parameter from `System Variables` and complete the expression by adding the subfolder.
You can also click on button `Evaluate Expression` to make sure the path is correctly evaluated.

[image]